# How to prevent CRLF injection (Http response splitting) in php

Tags: php, security, cakephp, newline, httpresponse

I did R&D on prevention of CRLF injection in php, but i didn't find any solution in mycase, as I'm using a burp suite tool to inject some headers using CRLF characters like the below.

```
// Using my tool i put CRLF characters at the start of my request url 
GET /%0d%0a%20HackedHeader:By_Hacker controller/action

//This generates an header for me like below
HackedHeader:By_Hacker
```

So i can modify all headers by doing just like above

This tool is just like a proxy server so it catches the request and gives the response and we can modify the response in the way we want.

So i'm just modifying the response by injecting some headers using CRLF characters. Now the Server responds to this request by injecting the CRLF characters in the response.

I'm just worried as header fields like Pragma, Cache-Control, Last-Modified can lead to cache poisoning attacks.

**header and setcookie contain mitigations against response/header splitting**, But these can't support me in fixing the above issue

**Edit**

When i request to mysite.com contact us page like below This is the request I captured in my tool like below

```
Request headers:
GET /contactus HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

And i get the Response HTML for the above request

Now for the same request using the tool i'm adding custom headers just like below

```
Request Headers:
GET /%0d%0a%20Hacked_header:By_Hacker/contactus HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 11:51:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 11:51:22 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Location: mysite.com
 Hacked_header:By_Hacker/..
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 2
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=120
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You can see the injected header **Hacked_header:By_Hacker/..** in the above response

**Is there anyway in php or apache server configuration to prevent such kind of headers' hack?**

Comment: How about validating the user input before using it!? I doubt that you'll get any better answers her unless you make this question about some specific code related problem.

Comment: Actually i'm modifying the request url by putting CRLF characters to inject some malicious headers using a tool, How can i prevent this as i'm concerned about security @ndm

Comment: My answer stands as is. If you have problems with validating/sanitizing input in specific contexts, then please add appropriate code to your question.

Comment: There is nothing to add any code related stuffs, Just adding CRLF characters to the requested url using some proxy tools like **Burpsuite** which leads to headers exploitation, I just wanted to prevent this to be happen as hackers use such tools to inject malicious headers @ndm

Here is the [link](https://prakharprasad.com/crlf-injection-http-response-splitting-explained/)

Comment: I already understood that, you are using a Pen-Test tool, and you want your code to be secure against header injections. However, you don't say anything about the specific context, ie where and how you are using the possibly malicous input, you don't show any code, so what kind of answer do you expect, other than that you have to validate/sanitize the user input?

Comment: @ndm i edited my question, actually this is what i'm doing to inject headers using tool, just suggest me any ideas to prevent response splitting

Comment: You are repeating yourself, and, no offense, I'm tired of doing so too, so this will be my last comment on this issue. HTTP response splitting can be avoided by validating/sanitizing user input before using it, that's all there is to this problem, period. How and where this needs to be applied depends on the context, which you refuse to elaborate on. If you need any help with a specific situation, then please, **explain it in detail**, and show the related code.

Comment: I feel you @ndm but I guess the question is interesting - in general. AnilKumar Check my answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why all the down votes - infact, it is an interesting question :)

I can see that you have tagged CakePHP - which means your app is using Cake Framework... Excellent! If you are using Cake 3 , it is automatically strip off : `%0d%0a`

Alternatively, where you receive the response header, just strip off `%0d%0a` and you are good!

Where things like these could be applied - a 3rd party API response or say.... a Webhook response! or a badly sanitized way to handle intl.. example : lang=en to lang=fr where the GET param is directly set as response header... That would not be a wise move!

Ideally, the responses will be as `GET` and not in the header but either way just strip the `%0d%0a` and you are good.

Answering your edit.

`You can see the injected header Hacked_header:By_Hacker/.. in the above response`

That injected header cannot be controlled or stopped, mate. We do not have control over what the other server does.

**The question is.. What do you do with the response header?**

**The answer is...** ***You sanitize it***, as [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) said you need to sanitize the input.. What you get as a response IS an input. As soon as you detect `%0d%0a`, discard the response.

Need code work?

```
<?php
$cr = '/\%0d/';
$lf = '/\%0a/';

$response = // whatever your response is generated in;
$cr_check = preg_match($cr , $response);
$lf_check = preg_match($lf , $response);

if (($cr_check > 0) || ($lf_check > 0)){
    throw new \Exception('CRLF detected');
}
```

Comment: The question is.. What do you do with the response header? FYI
I'm just worried as injected header fields like Pragma, Cache-Control, Last-Modified can lead to cache poisoning attacks. @Karma

Comment: Cache in that sense is browser based - it comes from YOUR server to the client's server. If an external 3rd party is responding with *something bad* it is your server that is getting the response. So, don't worry about it :)

Comment: Thank you sir, this really helped me a lot